# multivariate random forest on a community matrix

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to use random forest modeling to understand variable importance on community assembly - my response data is a community matrix.

```
library(randomForestSRC)

# simulated species matrix
species 
# site       species 1    species2     species 3
# 1             1            1            0
# 2             1            0            1
# 3             1            1            1
# 4             1            0            1
# 5             1            0            0
# 6             1            1            0
# 7             1            1            0
# 8             1            0            0
# 9             1            0            0
# 10            1            1            0


# environmental data
data
# site   elevation_m     PRECIPITATION_mm  
# 1        500                28
# 2        140                37
# 3        445                15
# 4        340                45
# 5        448                20
# 6        55                 70
# 7        320                18
# 8        200                42
# 9        420                22
# 10       180                8


# adding my species matrix into the environmental data frame
data[["species"]] <-(species)

# running the model
rf_model <- rfsrc(Multivar(species) ~.,data = data, importance = T)
```

but I'm getting an error message:

```
Error in parseFormula(formula, data, ytry) : 
  the y-outcome must be either real or a factor.
```

I'm guessing that the issue is the presence/absence data, but I'm not sure how to move past that.  Is this a limitation of the function?

Answer (score 1):

I think it MIGHT have to do with how you built your "data" data frame. When you used `data[["species"]] <- (species)`, you had a data frame inside a data frame. If you `str(data)` after the step I just referred to, the output is this:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
$ site     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ elevation: num  500 140 445 340 448 55 320 200 420 180
$ precip   : num  28 37 15 45 20 70 18 42 22 8
$ species  :'data.frame':      10 obs. of  4 variables: #2nd data frame
..$ site     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
..$ species.1: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
..$ species2 : num  1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
..$ species.3: num  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you instead build your data frame as `data2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(data,species))`
, then

```
rfsrc(Multivar(species.1,species2,species.3)~.,data = data2, importance=T)
```

seems to work because I don't get an error message, instead I get some reasonable looking output:

```
Sample size: 10
Number of trees: 1000
Forest terminal node size: 5
Average no. of terminal nodes: 2
No. of variables tried at each split: 2
Total no. of variables: 4
Total no. of responses: 3
User has requested response: species.1
Resampling used to grow trees: swr
Resample size used to grow trees: 10
Analysis: mRF-R
Family: regr+
Splitting rule: mv.mse *random*
Number of random split points: 10
% variance explained: NaN
Error rate: 0
```

I don't think your method for building the data frame you wanted is the customary way, but I could be wrong. I think `rfsrc()` did not know how to read a nested data frame. I doubt most modeling functions do without extra customized code.

Comment: Hmm, the issue is that in reality I have ~2000 species (microbial data), so I don't know how to group that many variables into the 'y' part of the equation.  At least we know that it isn't the p/a data though!  That makes sense that the function wouldn't know what to do with the nested data frame though.

Comment: Your question was about why the function was throwing an error. Your comment seems to have changed the focus: setting up the left side of your model when you have a lot of variables to refer to. You could ask a new question about that. Regardless, if the answer I supplied solved the question about the error, you should mark the question as answered.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that was the issue - your code worked, but I also ran the same code as above except my species df was abundance data (species <- matrix(abs(rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 20)),10,10)).  Even with the nested data frame, the model ran without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, using example data from the `vegan` package, of automatically constructing a formula that includes all of the species names in the response:

```
library(vegan)
library(randomForestSRC)
data("dune.env")
data("dune")

all <- as.data.frame(cbind(dune,dune.env))
form <- formula(sprintf("Multivar(%s) ~ .",
                        paste(colnames(dune),collapse=",")))

rfsrc(form, data=all)
```

Suppose we want to do this with 2000 species.  Here's a simulated example:

```
nsp <- 2000
nsamp <- 100
nenv <- 10
set.seed(101)
spmat <- matrix(rpois(nsp*nsamp, lambda=5), ncol=nsp,
                dimnames=list(NULL,paste0("sp",seq(nsp))))
envmat <- matrix(rnorm(nenv*nsamp), ncol=nenv,
                dimnames=list(NULL,paste0("env",seq(nenv))))

all2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(spmat,envmat))
form2 <- formula(sprintf("Multivar(%s) ~ .",
                        paste(colnames(spmat),collapse=",")))

rfsrc(form2, data=all2)
```

In this particular example we seem to explain -3% (!!) of the variance, but it doesn't crash, so that's a good thing ...